# Modifying Calendar VBA Project

Tags: vba, excel, ms-project

I want to copy from Excel to MS Project some data about a project. These data are gathered in a table in Excel and each column has a title describing the data below.

I need to identify the correct column from which extracting the data, but the method I tried gives me an error which I can't solve.

With the following code I'm looking to identify which columns contain the tasks of the project:

```
Set taskPos = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:AA2").Find("Task")
ColTask = taskPos.Column
```

ColTask should be the column containing the tasks from which I'd like to iterate the elements below.

```
For i = 2 To 10
     exTask = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("ColTask" & i).Value
Next i
```

With this method I get a

> runtime error 1004 vba application defined or object

and I don't really know how to solve it.

Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `ColTask` is a variable, not a string, so remove the quotes around it. In any case I think you would need `Cells(i,coltask)` as Range won't accept a number for the column.

Comment: In addition, when using `Find`, it's always good practice to first check the value is found before proceeding as otherwise you might get an error.

Comment: Thanks, it worked as you said! I checked "find" and it seemed to work, so I guessed it was the "range" command. Thanks again!